# Sniffing packets through router

Tags: networking, routing, ip, http-proxy

I would like to create a system like this.
[image]

The user would connect through a wifi network which would reroute all http requests and responses through the network card on a computer thus allowing that computer to sniff the packets. I have debian running on the computer. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: What's the OS on the router? If it's not a unix, we can't help you with that part.

Comment: I don't know what the os is on the router, it is a fairly simple drink home router.

Comment: There's a point where you'll want to duplicate the packets (one copy for the sniffer and one copy to go to the modem). According to [Howto: Copy/Tee/Clone network traffic using iptables by bjou](http://www.bjou.de/blog/2008/05/howto-copyteeclone-network-traffic-using-iptables/), found from [Copying packets from an interface to another](http://serverfault.com/questions/225178/copying-packets-from-an-interface-to-another), on Linux, this currently requires an additional kernel module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a 10/100 ethernet hub, a real hub, like a Netgear DS104.  Put it between the wifi and the router.  Hubs replicate traffic on all ports, so you can connect a separate machine to another port on the hub and sniff everything.

Comment: It seems that this will be the easiest way to do the job, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your brand of router specifically allows for that kind of interception (most don't unless you're talking about industrial grade stuff with triple digit costs and usage licenses) I'm afraid you're sunk; a better bet might be to install a wifi card in your computer and try to sniff the wireless traffic directly using something like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/).

Comment: I was thinking about getting a little creative with my hardware, What is I were to connect the Ethernet in on my router to my computer with a cat5 cable then use tshark to sniff the packets before redirecting all the data back to the ip of the modem. If that was confusing just tell me, ill draw up another diagram.

Comment: here is a pic http://gyazo.com/45210b1932d7140cdc160b3a672173c6.png

Comment: A wifi card and Kismet/wireshark will likely cost you way less in terms of overhead. In the setup you're describing in that picture you're essentially telling your router to use the sniffer box as default router, and the sniffer then forwarding traffic to the actual modem...

Answer (score 1):

You can connect modem directly to your computer and make router so send all traffic through your debian system. In this case you may do anything you want with packets.

P.S.: do you need something like [this](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/TransparentProxy.html)?

Answer (score 0):

```
tcpdump -i ethX -w capturefile net x.x.x.x/y
```

Where ethX the card which receives this traffic and `x.x.x.x/y` is the cidr of the wireless network. This should capture anything coming or going to this network and save it to "capturefile" file. Add `and port 80` in the end if you want only web traffic.

This looks like a "honeypot" setup. If you are trying to capture http sessions and/or other private information, this is illegal. Even if those users are trying to steal your internet connection. <strike>Unless you've acquired permission from those who use the wireless network, this is probably illegal.</strike>

EDIT:

I thought you already had setup the rerouting part. If you're asking how to reroute the specific traffic, it is possible but it depends on the hardware you have and probably I can't help you on that.

Comment: If it's his own wireless network I don't see why it'd be illegal to sniff on it - if I'd need written permission from every single customer of our ISP before being allowed to run tcpdump or wireshark to debug a problem I'd never get anything done.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough, my bad. I meant it is illegal if he wants to capture live http sessions and steal cookies or passwords. I can't see any other use for this setup, or he'd probably need a proxy server.